# How to list all models in a Rails project from the context of a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to determine how to do two simple tasks:

1. I would like to load all of a Rails Apps' models from the context of a Gem. For example say the Rails application is a blog and has authors, posts and comments. I would like the included gem to find, without knowing they exist, those models.
2. Again, from the context of a loaded gem, I would like to have the rails models available to me; So for example I could call Author.first, without knowing Authors exist, and I would like to have that information available to the gem.

So to summarize this question. **From the context of a gem, how does one load all models of a rails project, and have access to those models?**

This is my fast hack:

```
module ActiveTest
  class Base
    def listme
      ::ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.collect { |type| type.name }.sort
    end
  end
end


1.9.3-p286 :005 > a = ActiveTest::Base.new
 => #<ActiveTest::Base:0x007f8882bdd460> 
1.9.3-p286 :006 > a.listme
    NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
```

Comment: Is this list limited to only `ActiveRecord` models?

Comment: I'm not sure yet; I'm just starting to map out this idea. maybe either way?

Comment: What's your use case for this? That might lead to some other solutions. Why is it a gem when it's touching the app's models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ActiveSupport`

```
models = Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb"].map do |f|
  f.chomp('.rb').camelize # works with namespaces e.g. Foo::Bar::MyClass
end
```

If you want to turn those strings into the actual `Class` objects, tack on a `constantize` right after `camelize`

[camelize docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize)

[constantize docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize)

Comment: awesome!  => ["::Users::Fogonthedowns::Hack::Blog::App::Models::Author", "::Users::Fogonthedowns::Hack::Blog::App::Models::Post"]

Comment: models = Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb"].map do |f|
File.basename(f,File.extname(f)).camelize
end

seems to work better

Comment: These approaches only look in the main app directory -- scanning the directory won't return models defined in engines or other gems.  Be careful if you want access to those.